# Choppy Video on Intel 965GM running 14.10

Tags: video, 14.10, netflix

I have the most annoying problem, I experience choppy video on Netflix and YouTube. I'm running Linux 14.10 utopic unicorn 32 bit with two gigabytes of RAM.The graphics card is an Intel 965 GM and everything ran smoothly on Windows 7. I'm new to Linux and any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried a couple of things such as disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome and changing to XFCE lightweight desktop. Neither was any help

Answer (score 1):

Oh the pain of it all! Lol. For anybody who finds this I ended up downgrading to ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. Everything is running smooth as butter:-)

Answer (score 0):

Is this a laptop with speedstep?

I had a breakthrough on this with an old laptop - a dell Inspiron 6000 (with no battery to speak of as its too old)

First check you have good video drivers of course but then ..

I noticed the CPU clock was all over the place but because some of the graphics is using the CPU I also think there is some hysteresis in effect which makes the whole UI laggy.

I installed cpufreq-utils and with cpu-set -g performance and found that flash player in Firefox is now perfect. Also compiz/unity is now usable!

The CPU is generally at full speed but some compressed air, keyboard removal and a vacuum cleaner can be used to restore the cooling architecture and keep fan speeds to reasonable levels.

To make this sticky I found two files in /etc/init.d that put the acpi mode back to laggy 'on demand' - one I think is called 'ondemand' which I edited to comment out the effectual echo line (this script seems designed to change the power mode after 60 seconds startup) and another I think was called cpufrequtils which had a setting at the top.

With this and setting swappiness to 10 I think Ubuntu is usable on this laptop.

Flash player in Chromium not so good.

I think Windows might have better acpi (or perhaps is better at switching it based on power source by default)

Laptop back to life :)

Comment: hmmm thanks for the help:-) no luck though, changing acceleration methods from sna to uxa shows a lot of promise. Actually it smoothed out the graphics alot! but now I have a new issue where some launcher icons won't launch lol. Needless to say I'm still working on it. For anyone who's interested there's a good tutorial at http://linuxg.net/fix-slow-graphics-performance-on-ubuntu-13-04-intel-gpu/

Comment: Thanks I'll try that too -- maybe there's more to be had !!!